# Reset or refresh div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a dropdown list that has few options, if i choose one of the option the functionality of the dropdown box is got, i am using jquery only to highlight the chosen option. i would to be able to still click on the dropdown list and rechoose one of the option. lets say i made a wrong chose how can i change it without refreshing the page.

jquery

```
$("#list").live("click",function(){
   $(".choose").toggle();
   $("#list li").click(function(){
     var id = $(this).text();
     $("#list").html(id );
  });
});
```

html

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="choose">link 1</li>
  <li class="choose">link 2</li>
</ul>
```

i want to be able to re-choose from the list

Comment: You really need to rewrite your question in more clearer language and with details. That way we might be able to understand your question and help.

Comment: Your title says div, your code shows a ul with li elements... what are you trying to accomplish. Could you provide a jsFiddle example?

Comment: jsfiddle failed to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Your html is incorrect.
The first line -

```
<ul id="list>
```

should be

```
<ul id="list">
```